# Swapping the ISP supplied router on DSL connections that also supply TV

Tags: router, dsl, broadband, multicast, iptv

My ISP is [TalkTalk](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/) and I have one of their [FTTC packages](https://sales.talktalk.co.uk/product/fibre). With that I also have their [YouView TV service](https://sales.talktalk.co.uk/product/tv). Before getting this service I used my own routers, as ISP supplied ones didn't have the features I wanted. I would like to continue doing this however I've found if I swap the router for a different one the TV service stops working (Internet access works fine). I believe this may have something to with multicast, but my knowledge on multicast is slim at best.

I've used DD-WRT and OpenWRT routers in the past, and they support multicast in a fashion so I'd like to use these if I can. If not that's ok, but I would like to swap the router.

Is this possible, and if so what do I need to do to extract and replicate the settings to make the TV work?

Comment: What does your ISP say?

Comment: Your best bet is to go through your ISP like Xavierjazz suggests. Most ISP's allow you to turn their provided modem/router into a dumb router and use your own device. I can't imagine you're the first person that would have wanted to do this through them. Report back with your answer though.

Comment: Their line is that you must use one of their routers to use their TV service and that's it. Here is the web version of the answer, but I have spoken to them on the phone about this as well: http://help2.talktalk.co.uk/tv/do-i-need-use-specific-wireless-router-talktalk-plus-tv I do however know this is possible as I've seen people post about it on forums such as here: http://www.billion.uk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=621

Comment: So use their modem and simply connect your router to the modem.

Comment: How does your TV connect to their service?

Comment: @NevinWilliams just regular network cable on to the LAN, doesn't have a dedicated port or anything

Comment: hmmm, so they've probably got a special config that sends a certain kind of traffic to the TV;  If you knew what that was, you might be able to duplicate it on your own router...   How handy are you with `snmp`...?  An `snmpwalk` on their router, using a community name of `public` might allow you to figure out what ports/services might have to be configured to keep the iptv service running.

Comment: Oh, you could always try putting the iptv box into the DMZ zone.